# extract data from data base on basis of column data

Tags: php, mysql

i want to filter data from data base his one column is category in which data is like **"Beauty Supplies, Cosmetics Retailers, Hair Supplies, Hair Salons, Salons"** **"Salons"**  **"Salons, Barber"**  i want to filter row on the basis of category but till i am not get it

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
your query WHERE category IN('Beauty Supplies','Cosmetics Retailers','Hair Supplies','Hair Salons','Salons','Barber')
```

Comment: please answer with correct and complete sql syntax. This query will not work without quotes around string values.

Comment: this is my Query     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM csvdata");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
         
    $cat= array($row["categories"]);
    if($category[0]=='Barber' || $category[1]=='Barber' || $category[2]=='Barber' || 
             $category[3]=='Barber' || $category[4]=='Barber' || 
    {
    print_r($row);
    
    }
            
        }

Comment: i would say to better post it in your question.

Comment: and from where have you got this --$category-- variable.

Comment: o sorry i miss this line to mention   $category= explode(",",$row["categories"]);

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM csvdata");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $cat= array($row["categories"]);
    $category= explode(",",$row["categories"]);
    if($category[0]=='Barber' || $category[1]=='Barber' || $category[2]=='Barber' || $category[3]=='Barber' || $category[4]=='Barber' ) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

In this case, I would say you to use

```
your query WHERE category LIKE '%Barber%'
```

This will remove your **explode()** and **if loops**.

Comment: so in that case i would suggest you to make it as correct answer and make +1 to it.

Comment: but in some case it create a problem  like  if data is "salons,hair salons, tag salons" and if we use like %salons% then it read all value

Comment: well in that case you can remove the %. just directly use --LIKE 'salons'--.

Comment: when we use LIKE 'Salons' in that case they not read data after , data

Answer (score 0):

If you want all products of same category use

```
select * from tablename where category=categoryid
```